# How to get list of scubscribers from base Github Api

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2, github-api, okhttp

I am trying to get a list of subscribers from gitHub Api, for example, from the this link
https://api.github.com/repos/couchbaselabs/query/subscribers

i created the below interface to retrieve the list of subscribers, and i added the below code to make a Retrofit call to retrieve list of repositiories 
for a selected user.

for example, in my App I have a RecyclerView, each item/element in it contains repository name, avatar and description.
what I am trying to do is when the user clicks item number 4 in the Recyclerview I should provide the user with the list of subscribers to this repository. 
exactly as shown in the link
https://api.github.com/repos/couchbaselabs/query/subscribers

For this link, for example, I want to get a list of all subscribers. tha's how I coded the below posted interface. but when i run the code posted in the code section
below, i dont receive any thing.

please let me know how to get list of scubscribers given the above link

**code**

```
//to parse json data when an item is clicked
    holder.mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CLICKED @Position: " + position);
            Log.d(TAG, "subURL: " + items.get(position).getSubscribers_url());

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = RetrofitFactory.getOkHttpClient();
            Retrofit retrofitRef = RetrofitFactory.getRetrofit(mCtx, okHttpClient);
            SubscribersApiEndpointInterface service = RetrofitFactory.create2(retrofitRef, SubscribersApiEndpointInterface.class);
            Call<List<Subscribers>> call = RetrofitFactory.getSubscribers(service, "subscribers");
            RetrofitFactory.enque(mCtx, call, position);
        }
    });
```

**interface**:

```
public interface SubscribersApiEndpointInterface {

@GET("repos/{subscriber}/query/subscribers")
Call<List<Subscribers>> subscriberForName(@Path("subscriber") String subscriber);
```

}

**retrofit class**:

```
/** BASE_URL:https://api.github.com/ **/
public class RetrofitFactory {

    private final static String TAG = RetrofitFactory.class.getSimpleName();

    public static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {

        return  new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON").build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(Context ctx, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.BASE_URL))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static SubscribersApiEndpointInterface create2(Retrofit retrofitRef, Class<SubscribersApiEndpointInterface> subscribersApiEndpointInterfaceClass) {
        return retrofitRef.create(subscribersApiEndpointInterfaceClass);
    }

    public static Call<List<Subscribers>> getSubscribers(SubscribersApiEndpointInterface service, String name) {
        return service.subscriberForName(name);
    }

    public static void enque(final Context ctx, Call<List<Subscribers>> call, final int position) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Subscribers>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Subscribers>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<Subscribers>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Subscribers> result = response.body();

                    Log.d(TAG, "result.size: " + result.size());
                    List<Items> items = (List<Items>) result.get(position);
                    Log.d(TAG, "items.size: " + items.size());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Subscribers>> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the URL correct? The interface defines the path template: `"repos/{subscriber}/query/subscribers"`, you pass in `subscriber` as parameter. This does not seem to be correct. The `{subscriber}` variable actually identifies the repository in the path. Maybe you should try to pass in `couchbaselabs` as parameter.